# Python Flask cannot set debug mode to true

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have set up my first Flask project with PyCharm and this is my app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'TEST'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to run my project in debug mode so that I do not have to restart the server every time something changes. I provide the app.run function with a debug=True parameter, but this does not seem to change the debug flag. The application does start however and I do see "TEST" on the page, but this is with the debug flag set to False.

I also tried to directly change my env variable with os.environ["FLASK_DEBUG"] = "True", but this did not affect the flag also.

Any advice?

Comment: *this does not seem to work*  Please explain what you tried that didn't work

Comment: This debug=True has nothing to do with that.It just enables Werkzeug debugger

Comment: Are you running it using the flask command, with FLASK_ENV=development? See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/server/#server.

Comment: Run your flask app in command line instead of PyCharm. `python3 app.py`

Comment: *"this is my app.js file"* ???

Comment: @JohnsonZhou Thank you for the comment, when running it in the command line it correctly sets the debug flag

Comment: No problem! I'll post that as an answer down below, accept it to help others! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PyCharm, in Run/Debug config you can pass FLASK_DEBUG variable.
Try to set it to "1", not to "True".

Answer (score 1):

Run your flask app in command line instead of PyCharm. `python3 app.py`